# Unsure of how to ensure the Handler in my code will run correctly

Tags: java, android

The code below is a portion of the registration page of an application. I've recently asked a question on the errors in my code, and I was told that the `Handler` was always calling `onSignupSuccess`. How do I ensure that according to the success or failure of the boolean `emailsuccess`, the `Handler` will run `onSignupSuccess` and `onSignupFailed`, or the code under the `else` statement, respectively?

```
    link_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent login = new Intent(SignUp.this, Login.class);
            startActivity(login);
        }
    });

    signupbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            signup();

        }
    });
}

    public void signup() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Signup");

        if(!validate()) {
            onSignupFailed();
            return;

        }

        signupbutton.setEnabled(false);

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignUp.this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_DayNight_Dialog_Alert);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Creating Account");
        progressDialog.show();



            final String name = inputname.getText().toString();
            final String email = inputemail.getText().toString();
            final String password = inputpassword.getText().toString();
            final int number = Integer.parseInt(inputnumber.getText().toString());

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean emailsuccess = jsonResponse.getBoolean("emailsuccess");

                        if (emailsuccess) {
                            onSignupSuccess();
                            return;
                        }
                        else {
                            onSignupFailed();
                            AlertDialog.Builder cancel = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignUp.this);
                            cancel.setTitle("Registration Failed");
                            cancel.setMessage("Email already in database.");
                            cancel.setNegativeButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                            cancel.create();
                            cancel.show();
                            return;
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            };

            RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, email, password, number, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(SignUp.this);
            queue.add(registerRequest);

        new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        onSignupSuccess();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }, 3000);


        }

        public void onSignupSuccess() {
            signupbutton.setEnabled(true);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, null);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignUp.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Registration Successful!");
                        builder.setMessage("A confirmation code has been sent to your email.");
                        builder.setPositiveButton("Next", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SignUp.this, Confirmation_Sign_Up.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                     }
                   });
                   builder.create();
                   builder.show();;


        }

        public void onSignupFailed() {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Registration failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            TextView v = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
            v.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            toast.show();

            signupbutton.setEnabled(true);


        }

        public boolean validate() {
            boolean valid = true;

            String name = inputname.getText().toString();
            String email = inputemail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputpassword.getText().toString();
            String number = inputnumber.getText().toString();

            if (name.isEmpty() || name.length() < 2) {
                inputname.setError("Store name must be at least 2 characters");
                valid = false;
            } else {
                inputname.setError(null);
            }

            if (email.isEmpty() || !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
                inputemail.setError("Enter a valid email address");
                valid = false;
            } else {
                inputemail.setError(null);
            }

            if (password.isEmpty() || password.length() < 4 || password.length() > 10) {
                inputpassword.setError("Password must have between 4 and 10 characters");
                valid = false;
            } else {
                inputpassword.setError(null);
            }
            if (number.isEmpty() || number.length() != 8) {
                inputnumber.setError("Enter a valid phone number");
                valid = false;
            } else {
                inputnumber.setError(null);
            }

            return valid;




 }
}
```

EDIT: I removed the Handler and placed the `ProgressDialog` under `try` but now the `ProgressDialog` does not dismiss itself.

```
try {
                    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignUp.this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_DayNight_Dialog_Alert);
                    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Creating Account");
                    progressDialog.show();

                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean emailsuccess = jsonResponse.getBoolean("emailsuccess");

                    if (emailsuccess) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        onSignupSuccess();
                    }
                    else ........
```

Comment: Why are you using handler if you are already using Response.Listener

Comment: Without it the `ProgressDialog` does not show and I'm not sure why

Comment: but you are showing progressDialog out side the handler calling  progressDialog.show();

Comment: I tried putting the `ProgressDialog` inside of `try` but now the dialog will not be dismissed and `onSignupSuccess` will not run. I have edited the post to show what I did. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: your responseListener  is not being executed

Comment: Is it not being executed here: `RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, email, password, number, responseListener);`

Comment: The creation of `ProgressDialog` has to be outside of the `Response.Listener` just where you originally had it and `progressDialog.dismiss();` should be inside `onResponse()` (I'd put it before the `try` block)

Comment: I did that and the `progressDialog` does dismiss but it seems that the `try` and `cut` functions are just not working

Comment: Then there's something going wrong in your `try` block. Check the logs

Comment: the logs show no errors which is part of the reason I'm very confused